# farkas-minkowski theorem specific exmaple

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra, convex-cone

I was reading about farkas-minkowski theorem, which basically said a convex cone is polyhedral iff it's finitely generated. The theorem make sense, but when I played with some example I met the following problem:

If my cone is

$$\mathrm{cone}\{(1,2),(2,4)\} = \{ \lambda_1 (1,2)+ \lambda_2 (2,4)\mid\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \geq 0\}$$

Which is a silly but finitely genarated cone.

And the definition of ployhedral cone is $C = \{ x \mid Ax \leq 0 \}$ for some matrix $A$

**My question** is what's the matrix $A$ of this cone? And what's a general strategy to find such matrix if the given cone is finitely generated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your cone is spanned by $\{(1,2)\}$ only, are you aware of that? If I am not mistaken, then the matrix can be chosen as $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-2&\phantom-1\\ \phantom-2&-1\\ -1&\phantom-0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @M.Winter Yes I am aware of the duplication! I do believe your answer is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot!